# Queen of all Riddles

Tags: riddle

> I am the leader of merchants,
>   I am the only one of my kind,
>   Yet the smallest of eight.
>
> Look up and you'll find me,
>   Or down in the earth.
>   I'll tell you when it's hot or cold.
>
> I was once used to heal,
>   But now consume too much and you'll die.
>
> What am I?

This is my first riddle so not sure if it's too easy/too hard/not clear enough, so I'll add hints later on if needed.

Comment: Excellent riddle!

Comment: The Puzzling Stack Exchange is the hive; users are bees; the puzzles we make is our honey; the puzzles we answer are our flowers; the puzzles we *solve* in particular, is our pollen; and this is the Queen Bee :D $(+1)$ $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Mercury

Explanation in a minute..

I am the leader of merchants,

> The Roman god Mercury was the god of commerce and financial gain.

I am the only one of my kind,
Yet the smallest of eight.

> not sure about the "only one" bit, but Mercury is the smallest of the 8 planets in our solar system.

Look up and you'll find me,

> again reference to the planet

Or down in the earth.

> Mercury is a naturally occurring metal

I'll tell you when it's hot or cold.

> Mercury is often used (or maybe has been replaced (see below)) in thermometers.

I was once used to heal,
But now consume too much and you'll die.

> Mercury was some times used in medicinal applications before we knew that it was actually really harmful to humans.

Comment: Clearly far too easy lol, I'll wait for your explanation though.

Comment: How does it relate to the title?

Comment: The title is a reference to Freddie Mercury of the band Queen.

Comment: Only one of kind: Reference to being the only metal liquid at room temperature?

Comment: The "i'll tell you when it's hot or cold" for me at least, was the clue that made the riddle a lot easier than it would be without that clue. I'd recommend taking that out as it still is doable but just a bit more difficult (again, for me at least)

Answer (score 6):

I am the leader of merchants,

> Not sure on this one, but the first four letters are a start. Meh.

One of a kind

> I am the only metal that is liquid at room temperature

Yet smallest of eight

> smallest planet, since pluto got demoted

Look up and you'll find me,

> ...but not without a really good telescope!

Or down in the earth,

> ...as an ore, most commonly cinnabar, Mercury Sulfide

I'll tell you when it's hot or cold,

> ...if I'm in a glass thermometer, thanks to Herr Fahrenheit.

I was once used to heal,

> Elemental mercury still has medicinal properties, however

Consume too much and you'll die!

> ...or slowly go mad, as a hatter. Hatters used mercury to soften felt, and absorbed it through their skin. Over time, the mercury would cause loss of mental function, similar to lead poisoning, leading eventually to death.

I am

> Mercury.

.

> This is an edit.

Comment: Bingo on the second line

Comment: This is an excellent riddle for a first 'attempt'.

Comment: @Inazuma Gallium also is liquid at room temperature, or at least near room temperature.

Comment: @Nzall "Near room temperature" is not "at room temperature"

Comment: several metals have melting points slightly above room temperature.

Comment: -1 for the answer being a duplicate.

Comment: not all answers are complete when first posted, @manshu

Comment: Your this statement doesn't make sense to me. He posted the answer before you and there are no edits in his answer after your answer.

Comment: My answer is more complete, as @Inazuma noted in the first comment. I did miss the Freddie Mercury reference, though.

Comment: @ericm301 I hope this clears things up. There are a few things I looked for when accepting the other answer: 1) Andethal was first, and although his/hers *originally* lacked explanation, this was cleared up quite soon after. 2) His answer was slightly 'simpler' (i.e. my line of thinking) - particularly on lines five, seven - eight. 3) What wasn't answered, was supplemented by in the comments.

Comment: @manshu I disagree that this is a duplicate, hence the updates. Most of the justification in this answer is either worded differently, or a completely different approach (e.g. about the mad hatter).

Comment: @Inazuma - thanks for stepping in. I took the downvote to imply that I had copy/pasted another answer. I did not assume my answer was the "correct" one. Nevermind my bias; that's up to you.